I want to automatically populate a calendar sheet with scheduled meetings as team members select dates for events/meetings on different sheet
I think this is a really simple problem but I am struggling to find the right method/function.
I have a Google spreadsheet with a sheet called "Calandar"  which is just a column of each day of 2024, starting at 01/01/2024, and ending on 31/12/24.
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zNgzM0jJd84Pi_Z6rGK7qyMfX7qGMRkbpf4fIYpnhEE/edit?usp=sharing]
The second sheet is called "Data" and this is where the team members record the event type and the date they want.
I need the "Calandar" sheet to compare the dates and insert the events in the correct rows according to the dates supplied in "Data", and I need this to be automatic.
I have researched the xlookup function but I want to compare the whole range Calander!A2:A366 against the range Data!B2:B, and return the record in the corresponding column in Data!A2:A.
Nothing I have found seems to compare the range to the range - and then the duplicate dates in Data!B2:B are a problem too.


You may try this xlookup formula in Cell_B2 of Calendar tab:
=arrayformula(xlookup(A2:A&B1:F1,Data!B:B&Data!A:A,Data!A:A,))



try:
=IFNA(MAP(TOCOL(A2:A, 1), LAMBDA(a, TOROW(FILTER(Data!A:A, Data!B:B=a)))))


alternative:
=INDEX(TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(VALUE(TOCOL(A2:A, 1))&"", 
 TRIM(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TOCOL(QUERY(QUERY(Data!A2:B&"×", 
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), 
 "×", "¤", 1), "¤")), 2, 0), "×"))))



That is remarkable. Would there be a way to do the same thing but put the meetings, projects and Exercises in individual Columns? So for example, in Sheet "Calander", I would change the title of Column B to "Meeting", Column C to "Exercise" etc, and then just populate the columns with the relevant details?  I hope that makes sense - I have edited the Sheet "Calander" to show what I am looking for. - For info I will create a Data validation on the Sheet "Data" so the team members can only select specific events to avoid any extra columns being required in Sheet "Calander" as time goes by.
